# Hazelcast 3.10.4 InvocationMonitor timeout and backup-timeout

Tags: hazelcast

I have a Hazelcast server client setup:

Hazelcast cluster server nodes on Replicated Map as a KeyValue (String:Integer) store, and serve the Map.get(String) from hazelcast query clients.

There are some timeout backup timeout logs from Invocation Monitor at the server nodes.

Server Node 1 (10.4.1.25)

```
00:00:23.023 c.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor         : [10.4.1.25]:9785 Invocations:389 timeouts:23 backup-timeouts:0
```

Server Node 2 (10.6.1.25)

```
00:00:23.943 c.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor         : [10.6.1.25]:9785 Invocations:1324 timeouts:0 backup-timeouts:8
```

What does the timeout and backup-timeout mean?